# How to change tomcat version from 5 to 7 for a given Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I have created a Java Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse and selected Tomcat version 5.5.

It works fine under Tomcat version 5.5 and now I wish to switch it to version 7.

I tried to change the tomcat version using project properties as per the snapshots below, and every time I try to run the project under Tomcat 7, I get error "Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Configuration looks ok. Are both Tomcat servers running at the same time ?

Comment: No, I only start Tomcat 7, and only if the project "SimpleForm" is added to this server, it will fail to start.

Comment: Also, under Project Facets, Dynamic Web Module version is 2.4 and I cannot change it to 3.0. See new snapshot added to the main post above.

Comment: Yes, I also use Eclipse and I've faced this many times. The Dynamic Web facet locks, and the only way to "convert a project" is to actually create a new one, use the proper facet level, and copy/paste all resources into the new project. Changing the web.xml definition won't help changing the facet :(

Comment: Is there any server output in the `Console` view that you can show?

Comment: After several trial and error steps, I managed to switch from Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 7.0 and vise versa. I will shortly add the details as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

General idea to switch is to create a new project with the Target Version and then copy the configuration of the relevant sections to the project you want to switch it's Tomcat version.

**High level steps:**

- Project Properties / Target Runtime / select the Target runtime
- Project Properties / Java Build Paths / Edit Apache Tomcat entry and select the run time to add to classpath
- Project Properties / Project Facets / Select Dynamic Web Module and change the version
- Web Perspective / Navigator / ".settings" folder / copy the relevant lines from the file "org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml"
- Project Explorer / go to folder WebContent/WEB-INF and copy relevant parts from web.xml
- Stop the server, remove and add back the project, and R click on the project under the server, and select Clean Work Directory
- Run project under the target Tomcat version.

See snapshots below for more details.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]