# Cloning Eclipse project from BitBucket causes unexpected code errors

Tags: java, eclipse, git, bitbucket

I have uploaded my Eclipse project to BitBucket and decided to test how the cloning function works as I am quite new to using repositories. So I deleted the project from Eclipse and then used the "Clone a Git Repository" function to import my project back into Eclipse which worked correctly. However, there are now a few errors that pop-up in my code (errors that did not exist before) and I am trying to figure out what is causing this. Specifically:

```
- The method getSubmittedFileName() is undefined for the type Part
- The type ActiveSessionListener must implement the inherited abstract method HttpSessionListener.sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent)
```

I thought it might be caused by using an older version than Servlet 3.0 but that doesn't appear to be the case (it's configured to Servlet 3.1 as shown in the screenshot below). What could be causing these unexpected errors in my code and how can I resolve this?

[image: 1234]

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43295251/6309), this is a Tomcat version issue.

Do check your [Targeted Runtimes and Java Build Path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712415/6309), in order to reference Apache Tomcat v7.0.